# Orange blinking warning on Fujitsu Siemens RX-100

Tags: redhat, linux

I am managing an aged Fujitsu Siemens RX-100 server running raid-1, Red Hat Enterprise and Oracle 11-G. There are no apparent faults, but the orange triangle warning light is flashing.

How do I figure out what is causing the flashing light? I don't have ServerView or Nagios installed, and the only tool I have found so far (ln_sensors) have checked temperature and disk health without any apparent suspects. I am running SmartCtl and it gives me no errors.

I have replaced one of the disks earlier this year after an error reported by SmartCtl. The light did not come on at that time.

I am guessing that there may be other sensors on fans or elsewhere that is causing the light to flash. But how do I check those other sensors?

Thanks!!!

Update: The server could be as old as from 2009. We are not paying for support from the manufacturer (Fujitsu-Siemens), so they are not answering questions nor can I install ServerView. The server has been running without errors since I first asked this question, the light is still there but nothing has failed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sometimes there's lights on the inside of the machine that tell you where the fault is, but seeing how I have *no* experience with this hardware, I couldn't say. Perhaps the manual will tell you?

Comment: Welp, [here's the user guide for the S5 RX100](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/b7fh-5191-01en.pdf), and [here's the guide for the S3 RX100](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/b7fh-4381-01en.pdf).  They both seem to have sections about various warning and error states, and based on quickly skimming those manuals, I would say that a flashing orange triangle warning light would indicate a warning condition of some kind. You should probably check the manual and figure how to determine what the specific error is. Both manuals seem to make mention of management software you should have.

Comment: I'm a bit curious why you chose to ask the internet here, versus checking with the manufacturer... Even calling support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If upon a reboot you don't see specific POST errors that can be diagnosed by the user guides that HopelessNoob linked:

[S5 RX100 User Guide](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/b7fh-5191-01en.pdf)

[S3 RX100 User Guide](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/PRMRGY/b7fh-4381-01en.pdf)

Then you'll need to install the ServerView agent for Linux and get ServerView operational to diagnose the server's hardware.

If that's not an option, then you will need to contact Fujitsu Support for further assistance.  Specific OEM guidance would be recommended at that point.